# Cart add_fee() is not working in checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

In WooCommerce, I would like to make a discount without using coupons, and the discount calculation will be based on product price, with something like "take 3 products for the price of 2.

In **`function.php`** of my active theme I am using this code:

```
function promo () {
    if (is_cart()) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('des', 'woocommerce'), -50.00`enter code here`, true, '');
    }
 }
add_action ('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'promo');
```

My problem: This code doesn't work on checkout page.
If I force in review-order the discount appears, but the total value don't change. I think its not saving the fee.

How can I make it work (on checkout page)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> This hook is made for cart fees *(or discounts)*, **so you have to remove** **`if (is_cart()) {`** condition, **that why it's not working…**

Here is the correct functional code to achieve a "Buy 2 take 3" discount, that will make a discount based on line item quantity:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'discount_2_for_3', 10, 1);
function discount_2_for_3( $cart_object ){

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Initialising variable
    $discount = 0;

    // Iterating through cart items
    foreach( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

        // Getting item data from cart object
        $item_id = $cart_item['product_id']; // Item Id or product ID
        $item_qty = $cart_item['quantity']; // Item Quantity
        $product_price = $cart_item['data']->price; // Product price
        $line_total = $cart_item['line_total']; // Price x Quantity total line item

        // THE DISCOUNT CALCULATION
        if($item_qty >= 3){
            // For each item quantity step of 3 we add 1 to $qty_discount
            for($qty_x3 = 3, $qty_discount = 0; $qty_x3 <= $item_qty; $qty_x3 += 3, $qty_discount++);
            $discount -= $qty_discount * $product_price;
        }
    }

    // Applied discount "2 for 3"
    if( $discount != 0 ){
        // Note: Last argument is related to applying the tax (false by default)
        $cart_object->add_fee( __('Des 2 for 3', 'woocommerce'), $discount, false);
    }

}
```

> This will work for simple products, but not for product variations…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and works.